# How to create a JSP custom tag which marks a field readonly?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I want to create a custom tag which would mark a field readonly on JSP.
Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are elegant and ugly ways to solve this, I would start with the standard `if` tag unless you have particular needs, like this:

`<input type="text" name="name" <c:if test="condition">readonly</c:if>>`

Comment: Hi kennet, This approach might be bring too much of code for my requirement as I have multiple If-else statements(or lets say a Switch case), if this is true, make read-only, if that is true, make it disappear, if another thing is true, do something else.

Comment: Uh, do it inside the custom tag? By the way, the condition has to go in the `test` attribute.

Comment: Hi Balus, I think that could be done but again lot of if else kind of code. I am looking to develop custom tags similar to Spring Security's custom tags "isAuthorized" and all.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? You have a bean which has several checking methods to return the boolean checking result. Then use the `<c:choose>` ,`<c:when>` and   `<c:otherwise>` to  simulate the if -then-else

```
<c:choose>
      <c:when test="${!bean.isAuthorized}">
        <input type="text" name="name" readonly="readonly">
      </c:when>
     <c:when test="${bean.isCondition2}">
           ...........
      </c:when>
       <c:when test="${bean.isCondition3}">
           ...........
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
         ...............
      </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a custom tag would be the way to go here..

I understand that you don't want to bloat your code with multiple if else statements surrounding your readonly attributes.. If you have say 20 input fields that all need to be made readonly depending when a single condition is met (e.g. when a user has readonly privaleges).. you don't really want the processing overhead of running that single check 20 times..

Have you considered creating a seperate readonly view of your form? and and wrapping your if else condition around a set of includes? ok - you've got code replication (which there are ways to minimise), but it means you've got only 1 check instead of 20? Another advantage of keeping the read only view seperate would be that the data doesn't necessarily have to be displayed inside form elements and you're free to style how you want..

Comment: Hi raq, this is nice idea too. I am going to post what I am trying to come up with .. Maybe you guys can suggest or correct my approach?